# jQUery SlideDown - Text jumps to left

Tags: jquery, slidedown

This isn't the typical "jump" bug that gets reported.
I want users to be able to reaveal content between "slices" of an image:

http://ryandebraal.com/mindattic/

Unfortunately, when the content is shown it appears on the far right and then "jumps" to where its supposed to be once the animation is finished.

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Can you try `.slidebox-link{float:left;width: 50%; text-align: center;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the width of **class="slidebox"** as **670px;** The content will not go to right and then come left and vice versa while open and close

Comment: Thank you!!!
I was at the point where i was just adding random elements to different CSS classes, now it seems obvious :)